# List all packages in repository?

Tags: apt, repository

How I can list all packages a apt repository serves? Specifically before adding the repository to my system would be preferred.

Answer (score 6):

The best option I know is to reproduce the http get apt generates, by hand, and grep it for packages; something like

Check the deb line of the repository,

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/<name>.list
deb <url> <dist> <name>
```

Build a request like:
(this can be tricky)

```
$ curl -H 'User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3' <url>/dists/<dist>/Release
# or $ curl -H 'User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3' <url>/dists/<dist>/Release.gz | gunzip
Codename: <dist>
Architectures: amd64
Components: <name>
MD5Sum:
 ......66b4456ffdb000e8208d5d8ee5           287832 <name>/binary-amd64/Packages
 ......b4b8e5fe8d2d53588e745a3d20            47099 <name>/binary-amd64/Packages.gz
 ......d98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e                0 <name>/binary-i386/Packages
 ......9941158dbf2ac8332307610a5b               20 <name>/binary-i386/Packages.gz
...
```

That will tell you about the releases on this repository server
Build a second request:

```
$ curl -H 'User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3' <url>/dists/<dist>/<name>/binary-amd64/Packages | grep Package: | uniq 
# or $ curl -H 'User-Agent: Debian APT-HTTP/1.3' <url>/dists/<dist>/<name>/binary-amd64/Packages.gz | gunzip | grep Package: | uniq 
Package: mypacakge
Package: myotherpacakge
```

Change your arch as necessary, the previous release file should describe the paths and architectures well.

---

this is pretty tedious and heavy lifted, I hope someone can recommended a better option for this kind of check.

Comment: if anyone is interested in a script that does what this answer says, I committed it here: https://github.com/knocte/fsx/commit/df138db66dfbf56a7fab2a5429138faae158951d

Comment: once upon a time `dpkg-query --show --available` would have worked for apt, however the `--available` flag was disabled and dpkq-query can no longer enumerate the apt available list anymore. also, bash completion for apt somehow gets a list, so  there is probably a robust sample there too